# How do I transfer mp3 files from my Lumia 730 to MacBook Pro?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, itunes, mac

I have read about Windows Phone App for Mac but sadly it is not available from the store in India? Is there any alternative software? Will using a VPN help?

Answer (score 1):

Okay so I did a simple transfer from my SD card, inserting it in my mac! If anyone has a more elegant solution, do share!